# Using simple_form to build a double nested form with multiple association inputs

Tags: ruby-on-rails, associations, simple-form, multipleselection

If this is asked before please point me in that direction. I couldn't find it though.
In this application I am going to select some users on multiple teams who should receive a request for something. So I got the following models:

```
class Request < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :request_teams
  has_many :teams, through: :request_teams
  belongs_to :club
  belongs_to :requester, class_name: User, foreign_key: :requester_id
end

class RequestTeam < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :request
  belongs_to :team
  has_many :request_coaches
  has_many :coaches, through: :request_coaches
end

class RequestCoach < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :request_team
  belongs_to :coach, class_name: User
end
```

My approach was to first select the teams and submit them and afterwards select the coaches for those teams who should receive the request. The first step worked nicely with:

```
= simple_form_for @request do |f|
  = f.association :teams, as: :check_boxes, collection: @teams
```

But I couldn't get the next step to work.

```
= simple_form_for @request do |f|
  - for request_team in @request.request_teams
    = f.simple_fields_for :request_teams, request_team do |ft|
      = request_team.team.name
      = ft.input :coaches, as: :select, collection: request_team.team.coaches, input_html: { multiple: 'multiple' }
```

What seems to be the problem is that it agregates all the coaches in one array in the params rather than binding them to the appropriate request_team. The params received looks like: `"request"=>{"request_teams"=>{"coaches"=>["57","136371"]}}`

When i look in the rendered HTML the form input name looks like this:

```
name="request[request_teams][coaches][]"
```

And I expected it to look more like:

```
name="request[request_teams][some_request_team_id_here][coaches][]"
```

Is this possible? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You should try something like this `<% simple_form_for @request do |f| %>
 <% f.simple_fields_for :request_teams do |builder| %>
  <%= render 'request_team_fields', :f => builder %>
   <% f.simple_fields_for :request_coaches do |builder| %>
     <%= render 'request_coach_fields', :f => builder %>
   <% end %>'
  <% end%>   
 <%end%>  
<% end %>`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This is indeed possible. I just simply forgot to at accepts_nested_attributes_for.